# django template statement if != Null doesn't work

Tags: django, django-templates

@Fixed

I got problem with template tag `{% if ... in ... %}`. I'm trying to write statements if object don't exist ( equal Null ) then don't display anything. My model got few fields for links to SOcial Media like instagram, facebook, twitter etc. and not every company got every social media as we know. The problem is that those If statements doesn't work as they should (I checked django documentation), for example if company have added links to all social medias (twitter,fb,instagram,linkedin,website) it should display images with links to them. But if company have not added any link to social medias or website, it shouldnt display images. I don't know why those statements doesn't work

About images, if I remove the loop `{% for ... %} {% endfor %}`
then it is displaying all images even if company has not associated any links so this if statements also doesnt work then

/EDIT

I had to change those statements like

```
% if brand.website != None %}
```

to

```
{% if brand.website %}
```

and it fixed all

comp_view.html

```js
<div class="social-media">
{% for brand in brands %
{% if brand.website != None %}
    <a class="" href="{{ brand.website }}">
        <img src="/static/icons/website.png">
    </a>
{% endif %}

{% if brand.facebook != None %}
    <a class="" href="{{ brand.facebook }}">
        <img src="/static/icons/facebook.png">
    </a>
{% endif %}

{% if brand.instagram != None %}
<a class="" href="{{ brand.instagram }}">
    <img src="/static/icons/instagram.png">
</a>
{% endif %}

{% if brand.twitter != None %}
    <a class="" href="{{ brand.twitter }}">
        <img src="/static/icons/twitter.png">
    </a>
{% endif %}

{% if brand.linkedin != None %}
    <a class="" href="{{ brand.linkedin }}">
        <img src="/static/icons/linkedin.png">
    </a>
{% endif%}
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

views.py

```js
def brands(request, slug):
    brand = get_object_or_404(Company, slug=slug)
    return render(request, 'company/comp_view.html', {'brand': brand})
```

models.py

```js
class Company(models.Model):
    ...
    technologies = models.ManyToManyField('Stack')
    website = models.TextField(max_length=150, blank=True, null=True, validators=[URLValidator()])
    facebook = models.TextField(max_length=150, blank=True, null=True, validators=[URLValidator()])
    instagram = models.TextField(max_length=150, blank=True, null=True, validators=[URLValidator()])
    twitter = models.TextField(max_length=150, blank=True, null=True, validators=[URLValidator()])
    linkedin = models.TextField(max_length=150, blank=True, null=True, validators=[URLValidator()])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I got this, the problem was

```
{% if brand.website != Null %}
```

so I think django doesn't know what this statement mean. While I've changed it to

```
{% if brand.website %}
```

then it works as it should, If company has any link in website field, then it display image-icon, but if company has not a link in website field it doesnt display image-icon.

Sorry for opening answer, I've should already check the stamement without  `!= Null`